# Delegate Array in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How would I declare an array of Delegates in Excel VBA?

I am auditing excel spreadsheets and each column requires a different function to determine if the cell is good or bad.  Each function is of the same type,

```
Private Function checkCell(auditCell As Range) As Boolean
```

If I could declare a `Delegate` array I could push handling the order of the different `checkCell` functions to a function other than the one that actually audits the worksheet, which could become a nested loop iterating through my array of Delegates.

Is `Delegate` even defined in Excel VBA?  The VBA Editor is telling me *no*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK It's not available "out of the box". Having said that, you can achieve the `Delegate` functionality using WIN32 API calls (from `user32.dll`).

Here's sample code:

```
Option Explicit

'-----External Library Declaration which helps call the Proc by Address -----
Private Declare Function CallWindowProc _
                          Lib "user32.dll" Alias "CallWindowProcA" ( _
                              ByVal lpPrevWndFunc As Long, _
                              ByVal hwnd As Long, _
                              ByVal msg As Long, _
                              ByVal wParam As Long, _
                              ByVal lParam As Long) As Long


'-----This is the main function calling upon the proc via pointer -----
Public Sub test_delegate()
    Dim sMessage As String
    Dim nSubAddress    'As Long

    'This message will be passed to our Sub as an argument
    sMessage = InputBox("Please input a short message")
    'Get the address to the sub we are going to call
    nSubAddress = ProcPtr(AddressOf ShowMessage)
    'Do the magic! Function Called via Pointer...
    CallWindowProc nSubAddress, VarPtr(sMessage), 0&, 0&, 0&
End Sub

'-----This is the subroutine we want to call by address-----
Private Sub ShowMessage( _
        msg As String, _
        ByVal nUnused1 As Long, _
        ByVal nUnused2 As Long, _
        ByVal nUnused3 As Long)
'This is the Sub we will call by address
'it only use one argument but we need to pull the others
'from the stack, so they are just declared as Long values
    MsgBox msg
End Sub

'-----This function is used to extract the address of value to long -----
Private Function ProcPtr(ByVal nAddress As Long) As Long
'Just return the address we just got
    ProcPtr = nAddress
End Function
```

**Source:** http://unlimitedexcel.blogspot.com/2011/12/pointers-in-vba-huhh-delegates-in-vba.html

Comment: Are there other `user32.dll` functions that can replicate this functionality?

Comment: You mean replicate `Array` of `Delegates`?

Comment: Just `Delegate`s  I was hoping I could jury rig my own `Delegate` class and move on from there.

Comment: I just moved this code from an old 32 bit install of Excel to 64 bit, made `CallWindowProc` and `CopyMemory` ptrsafe and now get a type mismatch error on `nSubAddress = ProcPtr(AddressOf ShowMessage)`. Any idea if this can be made to work on x64 Excel?